# Defining field mapping for Service Area Calculation in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, service-area

I am building a model to generate service areas for health facilities and I'd like to have the facility ID instead of OID used in the Name field of the resulting service area layer. Outside of model builder I can accomplish this by defining the Name Property in the Location Analysis Properties dialog box.
[image: Load Locations Dialog Box]

In my model however, I can't enter a value for that property in the Add Locations tool. I have tried both doing it within the "Add locations" tool and defining a variable from the "Field Mapping" parameter neither approach lets me define the field for the Name Property.

Is there a way in model builder to define which field should be used for the Name in the resulting service area polygons?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3

[image: Relevant portion of the model]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error I solved my problem by creating a "Field Mappings" parameter for the "Add Locations" tool and then changing the properties from "A Single Value" to  "A List of Values". This made it possible to add the correct Field Name and send it to the tool.